# Can't update UIImage Variable in UIView based on pressing button in xib

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimage

I have a utility app for drawing.

In the xib there is a button that when pressed should update the UIImage variable.

```
- (IBAction)changeImage {
    UIImage *drawImageVar = [UIImage imageNamed:@"line.png"];
```

That line is in the MainViewController.m file.

The code that uses the drawImageVar is in the MainView.m as part of the

```
- (void) drawRect:((CGRect)rect {
```

I don't get any errors when it runs in the simulator, but it doesn't do anything.
BUT...
I have a yellow warning in the MainViewController.m file that says ..
Unused variable 'drawImageVar

I assumed that it's not being seen globally by and tried other suggestions for making it global(singleton, putting variable in the AppDelegate), but non of that seems to work.

Any advice??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YOUr drawImageVar is a local variable. You have to make it global or use the global variable instead

Comment: Making it global was the answer. However here is the the method I found at this link that worked. It involves the use of data containers and an app delegate. Worked like a charm! http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/54859-sharing-data-between-view-controllers-other-objects.html

Answer (score 1):

Mr.Michael H. The yellow warning says "Unused variable drawImageVar", it means you didn't use the vairable "drawImageVar" anywhere in your code after the initialization/declaration. So, you can use the variable inside of the method by local declaration, if you want to use this variable along the class you should create an object for UIImage in header (.h file). Hope you got any idea. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

add to your header file:

```
UIImage *drawImageVar;

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImage *drawImageVar;
```

add to your implementation file:

```
@synthesize drawImageVar;

- (IBAction)changeImage {
    drawImageVar = [UIImage imageNamed:@"line.png"];
    [drawImageVar setNeedsDisplay];
```

I assume you are using drawImageVar in DrawRect.

Comment: Good code, but I tried this already and it still doesn't allow the mainviewcontroller.m button to change the drawImageVar. See my reply to zon7.

Comment: Ok, for reference I think the reason it didn't work was down to imageNamed cacheing the image. [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path] would probably have worked fine.